# Applescript. Get properties of all instances

Tags: applescript, vlc

I have many instances of VLC open. I want to check the playing status of every instance like:

```
tell application "VLC"
    if playing = true then return
end tell
```

But it checks only one instance of VLC. How can I check all instances?

Comment: If you get a list of VLC processes with something like `set vlcIds to id of every process whose name contains "VLC"`, you can tell processes by process id to do something rather than telling by name, e.g. `tell (process id X) to do something`. So put your commands inside a loop iterating over the list of `vlcIds` and addressing each instance by process id.

Comment: This works thru "tell application "System Events"" but I don't get the property "playing" like i get thru "tell application "VLC"" I need to check the property "playing"

Comment: What's the real end goal here? What do you really want to have happen if a given instance is playing or not playing?

Comment: If VLC is playing then the news stream, I'm opening with a applescript is not executed.

Comment: This situation has me curious as to under normal circumstances how many instances of VLC do you have open at one time and why do you need to open a second instance anyway? If you are already running one instance and check what state it in, just don't start a second one if the first instance is playing and if the first instance isn't playing or paused use the first instance for the scheduled task. Or is it normal for you to have, say two instances open and be opening a third instance, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround answer based on your comment "I want to prevent a scheduled applescript to execute if a VLC instance is playing." and the other information that has been presented in other comments and answer posted prior to this one. Also, by execute, I'm assuming you mean execute any additional code in the script that started on schedule.

Also note, this may not be perfect however its being presented to give it a try.

On my system, when an occurrence of VLC is open and without content loaded, after the initial percent of CPU usage spikes it quickly settles to 0% and with content loaded but not playing it's less than 5% and typically less than 3%. If it's playing it's typically always greater than 5%.

This of course may vary on your system, so you'll need to monitor over a period of time polling CPU usage to see how it fluctuates on your system to see what the sweet spot is.

The following example AppleScript code when placed at the beginning of the code in the scheduled AppleScript, prior to code in your script to trigger whatever with VLC, will abort processing the rest of the script if the percent of CPU usage of other instances of VLC is equal to or greater than 5%.

```
set |VLC%CPU| to paragraphs of text of ¬
    (do shell script "ps -Ac -o %cpu -o command | grep [V]LC ; exit 0")
repeat with thisItem in |VLC%CPU|
    if first word of thisItem as integer ≥ 5 then return
end repeat
```

Comment: Yes there is a problem with this solution. The CPU usage of  a standby high resolution movie is bigger then a running low resolution movie.

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be to  rename the instances by making copies of the application, and giving them new names such as VLC1, VLC2. You can do this by going to the applications folder and copying the VLC Application. Then paste it within the same folder to create the app "VLC copy". Then rename each copy you create. The copies will now show in the applescript dictionaries.

You can now use a tell block for each instance to check if it's playing. You just need to make sure that you open the correct instance numbers for the number you have playing. E.g. don't open "VLC1" and "VLC3" if you only have 2 instances, or close a lower instance number. By having the `if c is equal to` statement it won't open that instance of the application by executing the tell block.

If you have all instances open you could remove the loop and the if statements and just check if they're playing or not.

```
on getCount()
    tell application "System Events"
        set p to processes whose name contains "VLC"
        set theCount to count of p
        return theCount
    end tell
end getCount

set appCount to my getCount()
if appCount is greater than 0 then
    repeat with c from 1 to appCount
        if c is equal to 1 then
            tell application "VLC1"
                if playing is true then
                    log ("playing 1")
                end if
            end tell
        end if
        if c is equal to 2 then
            tell application "VLC2"
                if playing is true then
                    log ("playing 2")
                end if
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

So far the half solution I do is:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if (name of application processes whose frontmost is true) = {"VLC"} then return
end tell
```

So I check is it frontmost. Usually if I run a movie it is frontmost. I would prefer the "is playing" variation but... ok, what can I do.

Comment: That should read `if name of application process whose frontmost is true = "VLC" then return`.  The two changes I recommend are `processes` →  `process` (you can't have more than one process which is frontmost); and therefore `{"VLC"}` → `"VLC"`.

Comment: But generally, this is a really unreliable means of testing.  You can't guarantee *VLC* will be frontmost, even if it is playing fullscreen; and if it's **not** frontmost, this still doesn't imply that no other instance of *VLC* is playing in the background somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm understanding the nature of your query more now.  I was previously a little confused about what your objective was, but now I'm gathering it's simply to determine whether **any** *VLC* instance is playing or not.  Is that correct ?

But that you do **not** need to know *what* is playing or in which window it's playing ?

And am I correct in saying that you only need to discover that a single instance out of many is playing, in which case this is sufficient to prevent some other AppleScript from executing ?  Or, put another way, that other AppleScript will execute if and only if no instance of *VLC* is playing ?

I believe that's achievable.  Although we can't use the `playing` property of the *VLC* application object, we can use properties/attributes of *VLC* processes/windows to determine whether or not each instance of *VLC* is playing.

```
    tell application "System Events"
        set _W to a reference to window 1 of (every process whose name is "VLC")
        set _title to the value of attribute "AXTitle" of _W
    end tell
```

That is literally all you need, as the `AXTitle` attribute returns very predictable data depending on the state of *VLC*:

▸ **If VLC is playing and NOT fullscreen:** `_title` evaluates to a non-empty string (specifically, it contains the name of the video file or the path to the internet stream).

▸ **If VLC is NOT playing:** `_title` evaluates to "VLC media player".

▸ **If VLC is playing and IS fullscreen:** `_title` evaluates to an empty string ("").

Therefore:

> If `_title` = "VLC media player", then *VLC* is **not** playing; otherwise, *VLC* **is** playing.

Utilising this fact, in order for your other AppleScript to be allowed to execute, we want **every** `_title` value representing each instance of *VLC* to be equal to "VLC media player".  If there is even one value in `_title` that is anything other than that, then the assertion fails and the script can terminate, or do whatever it needs to do to prevent the execution of some other script.

I chose to simply count the number of attributes returned with the name "AXTitle" and a value other than "VLC media player".  The number returned is equal to the number of *VLC* instances currently playing:

```
    tell application "System Events" to count ¬
    (the attributes of window 1 of ¬
        (every process whose name is "VLC") whose ¬
        name is "AXTitle" and ¬
        value is not "VLC media player")

    if result is not 0 then return
```

Comment: Would be great but doesn't work. I get the same result for "VLC is not playing in full screen" and "VLC is playing in full screen" = Empty string "". OSX 10.9.5

Comment: @Atalantia Can you be more specific ?  What values for `AXTitle` do each of those states return ?  What versions of *VLC* and MacOS are you running ?

Comment: VLC 2.2.8 OSX 10.9.5 If VLC is playing in no full screen, the title of the movie is returned. If VLC is not playing in no full screen, the title of the movie is returned. If VLC is playing in full screen, "" is returned.  If VLC is not playing in full screen, "" is returned.

Comment: *VLC* can't be in fullscreen if no movie is playing.  I'm confused by {*VLC* **not** playing → title of movie or "" is returned}.  Do the actual window titles themselves agree with this ?  Well, in that case, we'll have to pick a different attribute or property, or a combination of two.

Comment: But do let me know what the actual window titles say in each case, because there's an attribute called `AXTitleUIElement` that reads the actual text element of the title bar and returns its value.

Comment: Also, have a look at the `name` and `title` **properties** of `_W`.  So replace `set _title to the value of attribute "AXTitle" of _W` with `get name of _W` or `get title of _W`.

Comment: @user3439894 Fair enough, but for the purposes of atlantia's goal—which is to determine whether or not the rest of the AppleScript should be allowed to execute—I think this is not an important distinction.  I wish I had an earlier system to run through the various attributes and properties myself.  I fear atlantia is giving up, even though I feel quite certain that the solution is roughly how I've laid out, but simply with a different property or attribute for the earlier systems.

Comment: @user3439894 That's precisely what I'm saying: if it's fullscreen and paused, then this should be treated the same as if it were playing. Or have I misinterpreted something ?  I was under the impression that the additional AppleScript would get executed if and only if there are zero instances of *VLC* either playing or paused (i.e. all must be stopped).

Comment: Hey, I posted a comment to the OP, that hopefully he'll reply to, and it will be interesting to see what he has to say. I really do not see why more then one instance needs to be open to begin with as its current state is saved in the event if I start something else while it's currently running or whatever, I can then get right back to it. So, I'm failing to see why a second or third instance is even necessary.

Comment: @CJK Sorry cause of the time shift I was taking a nap. Yes, an additional script is prevented from executing if one or more instances of VLC are playing. The test I made above was done all with the same movie. The title isn't in the metadata of the movie, only in his file name. They must be stopped you said. Maybe thats the point. Some of the movies are paused. The problem is, if a movie in full screen is playing or paused returns the same result. An empty string: ""

Comment: I try "properties of _W". It returns the same values for all if the movie is playing or paused.

Comment: Sorry, have had internet troubles the last couple of days.  If I’m interpreting your needs correctly, it doesn’t matter that a movie returns the same result when it’s playing or paused; only that it returns a unique result when it’s stopped, no?

Comment: No, I need a unique return when the movie is playing. I got a solution now at the "NoDisplaySleepAssertion". VLC prevents displays from sleeping when playing so:   <pre>  if (do shell script "pmset -g assertions|grep 'NoDisplaySleepAssertion'") contains "(VLC)" then return <code>
    does the job. PS: Shit formatting system  in this forum.

Comment: It’s a great formatting system if you use it correctly.  But, that aside, does this mean that *VLC* will prevent displays from sleeping while a movie is actively playing; but if you pause the movie, the display is free to sleep…?  Asking for my own benefit.